# Symfony 2.7 + Sass + Assetic: Styles not applied/visible when using app_dev.php

Tags: css, symfony, sass, assetic

I would like to use `Sass` based styles in my Symfony 2.7 WebApp. So far I have used `Compass` to compile Sass files (located not in the `web/` dir but within the Bundles) to CSS files. This works fine, but on a new server Ruby is not available and thus Compass is not an option anymore.

Following the [Symfony Docu](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/frontend/assetic/php.html), I have added leafo/scssphp to the project and activated in the config file:

```
# app/config/config.yml
assetic:
    filters:
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
        # ...
```

The Sass files within the `Twig` templates:

```
{% stylesheets 
    'MyMainBundle/Resources/styles/sass/header.scss'
    filter="scssphp" 
    output="css/header.css" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

This works fine when using Symfony in **non-dev** mode:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

The file `web/css/header.css` is created and everything works without any problem. However, when using the `app_dev.php` front controller, no styles from `header.scss` are applied. Only styles from other files which are linked directly (without using Assetic) are rendered.

This strange, because when I inspect the generated/loaded HTML file, the style sheet seems to be included correctly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app_dev.php/css/header_header_1.css" />
```

Calling `/app_dev.php/css/header_header_1.css` directly shows the style sheet with all its styles.

So all styles seem to be in place. Everything as it should be. Except, that no styles are being rendered.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem: The css file was transferred with `Content-Type: text/html`instead of `text/css.` This was caused by the format_listener settings of the `FOSRestBundle`. Adding css to the accept rules solved this. The css files are now transferred as `text/css` and everything works fine.